# ActionScript 3.0 integer overflow?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, integer, overflow

I have an old AIR file that works fine. I tried to recompile it but the resulting airfile is buggy.

After digging in the code, i found that at some place strings are parsed to ints, and that the resulting int does not correspond to the string.
So i made a simple Actionscript file and executed the code:

```
var test:int = parseInt("3710835714");
```

and the variable will have the value

```
-584131582
```

So this looks like an overflow. But i'm surprised that the air file i have (which i didn't compile myself) runs just fine. So I wonder - does the internal representation of int somehow depend on what version of the Flex or AIR sdk libraries one is using for compiling?

//edit: it seems it boils down to this test:

```
        var obj:Object = new Object();
        obj.val="3710835714";
        var test1:Boolean = (obj.val==-584131582);
        var test2:Boolean = (int(obj.val)==-584131582);
```

this evaluates for me to

```
test1=false;
test2=true;
```

however - the this old AIR file seems to evaluate both cases to true. How can that be?

Comment: what happens if you use uint instead of int?

Comment: well that should work of course, because then the values are identical (since 3710835714 fits into a uint). but the question is, why my old AIR file evaluates the first test (without code changes) to true? is either the internal integerrepresentation larger or is there a difference in how strings and integers are compared by == ?

Comment: my _guess_ would be that the string is converted to a uint and then false/true comparison depends on whether is a strict bitwise comparison or a actual value comparison (i don't think I'm explaining that well.. )

Answer (score 3):

It  is happening due to Give number exceeds ActionsScript [Int](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/int.html) limit

*The int data type is stored internally as a 32-bit integer and comprises the set of integers from **-2,147,483,648 (-231) to 2,147,483,647** (231 - 1),*

and number **3,710,835,714** exceeds it by **1563352067**

but your parse result shows compiler is considering it as [Uint](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/uint.html), whose Max limit is **4,294,967,295** i.e

**-584131581 = 3,710,835,714 - 4,294,967,295**

You should use [Uint](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/uint.html) or [Number](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Number.html) for big whole-numbers/integers

this blog may helps you
[ActionScript 3 Number data type problem with long integer values](http://abadjimarinov.net/blog/2010/06/24/ActionScript3NumberDataTypeProblemWithLongIntegerValues.xhtml)

Hopes that works

Comment: this all is absolutely clear - my actual question is why the exact same code worked when it was compiled earlier?

Comment: which version(s) of AIR/FLEX SDK you are using?, did you build app earlier with different/older version?